# How to make a modal bootstrap popup by calling the product id to get details in the modal?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-modal

i tried to make a popup modal bootstrap by clicking details button. In the modal i can call product details using pdo when i click details button i can get the productnum(id). Unfortunately, the productnum (id) always call the last row of data productnum(id)... how can i call the product productnum(id) properly to insert at the modal bootstrap javascript?

```html
 <?php
      // Read
         $per_page = 10;
      if (isset($_GET["page"]))
        $page = $_GET["page"];
      else
        $page = 1;
      $start_from = ($page-1) * $per_page;
      try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("select * from tbl_products_a170804_pt2 LIMIT $start_from, $per_page");
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
      }
      catch(PDOException $e){
            echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
      }
      foreach($result as $readrow) {
      ?>   
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $readrow['fld_product_num']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $readrow['fld_product_name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $readrow['fld_product_price']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $readrow['fld_product_brand']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $readrow['fld_product_quantity']; ?></td>
        <td>
          <button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs openPopup" role="button" id="details" value="<?php echo $editrow['fld_product_num']; ?>" >Details</button>
           <?php if($pos==="Admin" || $pos==="Supervisor" ){ ?>
          <a href="products.php?edit=<?php echo $readrow['fld_product_num']; ?>" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" role="button"> Edit </a>
          <a href="products.php?delete=<?php echo $readrow['fld_product_num']; ?>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete?');" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" role="button">Delete</a>
        </td>
      <?php } ?>
      </tr>
      <?php } ?>
```

here is my modal bootstrap code

```
 <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h3 class="modal-title">Product Details</h3>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">&times; Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This the javascript.. when i click it, it always give me the last row id

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn").click(function(){
        $('.modal-body').load('products_details.php?pid=<?php echo $readrow['fld_product_num']; ?>',function(){
    $('#myModal').modal({show:true});
});
    });
});
```

**Quetions: ** how can i call the exact product num properly to put in the modal javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have solve this quetion. Just us data-url

```
<button 
      data-href="products_details.php?pid=<?php echo $readrow['fld_product_num']; ?>"
       class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" role="button">Details</button>
```

this is my jquery

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn").click(function(){
       var dataURL = $(this).attr( "data-href" )
        $('.modal-body').load(dataURL,function(){
    $('#myModal').modal({show:true});
});
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to store id of the product somewhere ( ex. `data-attribute` in `.btn` element ) and use it later in `jQuery`

```html
<a href="products.php?edit=<?php echo $readrow['fld_product_num']; ?>" 
  data-id="<?php echo $readrow['fld_product_num']; ?>"
  class="btn btn-success btn-xs" role="button"> Edit </a>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".btn").click(function() {
    const id = $(this).data( "id" )
    $('.modal-body').load(`products_details.php?pid=${id}`,function() {
      $('#myModal').modal({show:true});
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: it doesnt work....i guess my data-id received some value but the ways i get it back at jquery is wrong. how to get back data-id properly in  products_details.php?pid=${id}